# Реализация конструктора копирования(перемещения) через равно копирования (перемещения)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор-копирования, оператор-присваивания

Хорошая ли идея писать так:

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(const A& other)
    {
        //Вызов равно копирования.
        (*this) = other;
    }    

public:
    A& operator =(const A& other)
    {
         //Какая-то реализация...
         return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто жуткая! потому что в присваивании вы должны аккуратно уничтожить объект, в который копируете - а для этого первоначально его создать...

Вот наоборот - куда лучше :)

Пишем функцию `swap(A& other)`, которая обменивает содержимое двух объектов, и конструктор копирования. После этого присваивание (а не "равно") пишется через конструктор копирования как

```
A& operator=(const A& other)
{
    A tmp(other);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Даже проверять на равенство `this == &other` - и то необязательно, отработает корректно. Конечно, можно его добавить - чисто вящей эффективности для...

Можно даже короче -

```
A& operator=(A other)
{
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Корректно ведь обработает до тех пор, пока мы динамически память не выделяем? Эту проверку, как я знаю, нужно делать, чтобы избежать проблем с самоприсваиванием?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотел бы еще уточнить. А если я предварительно создам объект вызовом делегированного конструктора тоже будет плохо?

Comment: @Harry - а конструктор без const ref уже по стандарту ? (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: @mld8nk, варианты co `swap` правильно обрабатывают самоприсваивание.

Comment: @KoVadim Нет. Но у меня такого конструктора и нет (он бы просто не работал из-за бесконечной рекурсии) - есть только оператор присваивания без `const ref` во втором варианте. А на него тоже наложены такие же ограничения?

Comment: *если я предварительно создам объект* - да можно как угодно. Работать будет. Просто неэффективно...